# C Program Push button counts continuously when pushed for a long time

Tags: c, button, push, atmel

It counts from 0 to 3 only. Adds 1 when down is pressed and subtracts 1 when up is pressed. The problem is when i hold it, it counts continuously. I want it to count only once even if i hold the push button for a long time. I'm using ATMEL SAM3X microcontroller if that helps. And that the push buttons are logic 0.

```
#include "..\ASF\common\services\gpio\sam_gpio\sam_gpio.h"
#include "delay.h"
#include "sam3x_ek.h"
#include "Press_Counter.h"

signed int UP_DOWN;
signed int LEFT_RIGHT;

void Press_Counter()
{
    unsigned int Button_State;
    Button_State=1;

    if(UP)                  //if UP is pressed
    {
        delay_ms(50);
        if(Button_State==1)
        {
            UP_DOWN--;      //decrement
            if (UP_DOWN<0)
            {
                UP_DOWN=0;  // To ensure that the minimum value is 0
            }
        }
        Button_State=0;
    }

    else if(DOWN)           //if DOWN is pressed
    {
        delay_ms(50);
        if(Button_State==1)
        {
            UP_DOWN++;      //increment
            if (UP_DOWN>3)
            {
                UP_DOWN=3;  // To ensure that the maximum value is 3
            }
        }
        Button_State=0;
    }

    else
    {
        Button_State=1;
    }

    count_UP_DOWN=UP_DOWN;  // Get the value of counter cause imma use it later
}
```

Comment: You might need to add a state-variable saying that the button is pressed, and not do anything while it's set.

Comment: Sorry the signed int LEFT_RIGHT was supposed to be signed int count_UP_DOWN.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg could­­ you explain that a little further. sorry i'm new in programming(as you can see in my code) and i don't quite understand how that works.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to change the values of your  program when you release the button, since you don't really wan't the button to change the value while you're pressing it.

So you'll have to remember the state of the button in the following manner:

```
delay_ms(50);
If(Button_pressed==1){
    if(previous_state==1){
        //Do nothing
     }
    else {
        UP_DOWN++;
        previous_state = 1;
        If(UP_DOWN > 3){
        //Do your counter setting stuff here
    }
}
else {
    previous_state = 0
}
```

This should work; put it within the two if-clauses `if(UP)` and `if(DOWN)` and adjust accordingly.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: I changed my suggested solution accordingly; the while solution is a solution, but you're right, it's not the best and proper one. @Joshpbarron

Answer (score 0):

only modify the count on state transitions of the button

rather than counting every time the code checks the state of the button.

so add a variable to remember the last state of the button.
(do not put this button on the local stack
 as the prior state will be lost/forgotten each time 
 the press_counter() function is exited.
 suggest placing the remembered state variable 
 in file global address space.)